# which directory should i use for files not available for users?

Tags: swift

I have an app for ipad and iphone and since users can download files in there i've enabled `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` in my plist, so users can find the files. (I store them in `FileManager.default.url(for:.documentsDirectory,...)`)

However the app also needs to write texts to files, that shouldn't be accessable for the users. Where should i store those?

Comment: Are you looking a place to store files that won't be accessible to the user or just a place that won't be easily findable by the user?

Comment: the first one. I think `.libraryDirectory` is the one i need

Comment: You can use `.libraryDirectory` but it will be accessible. In fact, it's not really possible to write a file from an app that the app's user will be unable to read.